# What does 5LL mean in DBFZ?

Tags: dragon-ball-fighterz

New to fighting games and having trouble reading combos. I understand that 5L stands for standing light attack in Dragon ball FighterZ but can't find a source explaining the extra L in 5LL. Also there is an instance of triple L. Here's the source http://www.dustloop.com/wiki/index.php?title=DBFZ/Trunks/Combos

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really know, but shouldn't an additional L mean "another L attack"?

Comment: @Nolonar I think you have the answer, post it as an answer for OP to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically means that you miss the first and hit the next.
Same with triple, you miss the first two, but land the third.

To clarify: Simply stand just out of reach to miss the first 5L but hit the next one, this is called a 5L

Someone asked:

> Could anyone explain what a 5LL whiff is? Does it mean that you miss your 5L or something?

Someone replied:

> Miss (intentionally) your first standing light and hit the next.

https://www.reddit.com/r/dragonballfighterz/comments/87xe65/psa_starting_a_combo_with_5ll_by_whiffing_5l_for/

Comment: This is incorrect. 5LL does not mean "miss the first". 5LL simply means press 5L (standing light), then follow up with another L.